# Is there a name for this geometric property of metric spaces?

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, metric-spaces

My research has lead me to metric spaces $(M, \rho)$ which have the following geometric property:

> Suppose $x, y \in M$ and $r, s > 0$ such that
>
> - $(x, r) \neq (y, s)$,
> - $B[y; s] \subseteq B[x; r]$,
> - $S[y; s] \cap S[x; r] \neq \emptyset$
>
> Then
> \begin{align*}
> 0 &= \lim_{\delta \to 0^+} \operatorname{diam}(B[y; s + \delta] \setminus B(x; r)) \\
> &= \lim_{\delta \to 0^+} \operatorname{diam}(B[y; s] \setminus B(x; r - \delta)).
> \end{align*}

That is, if you take two nested balls touching on the sphere, and either enlarge the smaller one, or shrink the larger one, you can generate an arbitrarily small set difference.

I was wondering if this particular property of metric spaces already has an established name? I'd also be very interested if it has a name in the context of normed linear spaces, or if it is equivalent to some combination of the usual properties in geometry of Banach spaces (e.g. local uniform rotundity). If this property has an established name, I would appreciate a reference as well.

Thanks in advance. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: What is $(x,r)$? $B[x;r]$? $S[y;s]$?

Comment: $(x, r) \in M \times (0, \infty)$ is just an ordered pair. $B[x; r] = \{z \in M : \rho(x, z) \le r\}$, the closed ball centred at $x$, with radius $r$. $S[x; r] = \{z \in M : \rho(x, z) = r\}$, the sphere of the aforementioned ball.

Comment: Upvoted to undo the instant downvote with no explanation, although I can't really evaluate the content of the question -- to the anonymous downvoter, congratulations on earning Theo +8rep for this question.

Comment: @AlecRhea Thank you! I think Piotr gave me the downvote, as his comment originally said something like "This does not look like the forefront of mathematics", and the comment and downvote were given within a second of each other. The feedback here is, I guess, this question is not sophisticated enough for the site? I'll see what others have to say about it.

Comment: That was me with the downvote. I honestly looked at the question for a very short time and I was confused with the notation so my impatient reaction, but I was wrong and removed the downvote.

Comment: Thank you @Piotr. I should remember that the notation I use isn't universal!